# How to recall state of collapsed columns on page reload and display automatically

Tags: javascript, php, css, html

I am working on a game with a play menu with collapsible columns. I want to use html5 to remember the state of the columns so that when page is refreshed user does not have to readjust their columns. I have tried several times to implement this with other codes on this site and I just cannot seem to get it to work. I am no good a javascript. I am thinking there should be an onload function to recall local storage variables but my brain is fried on how to implement this. I never had formal training on computers.

I am linking (i hope) my project on github. The page in question is called new.php.

Bear with me I am new at GitHub as well, but if you could link me a code I could copy/paste or download I would be eternally grateful! I will be studying manuals and fiddling with it while I wait on a response. Hopefully I will get this on my own but at this point its just not likely.

[my github project](https://github.com/AliciaAMT/final)

Comment: Welcome. As per Stack Overflow guidelines, code must be included in the body of the question. 1) if the link should become unavailable, then the question would be rendered useless, downgrading the value of SO. 2) people are more likely to choose *your* question if all the details are here. Please click `edit` to update your question with an MVE version of your code so volunteers can quickly see your issue. Please also read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [ How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Good Luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned using [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), so here's what you could do:

In these functions:

```
function openNav1() {
    document.getElementById("myNav1").style.height = "100%";
}
function closeNav1() {
    document.getElementById("myNav1").style.height = "0%";
}
function openNav2() {
    document.getElementById("myNav2").style.height = "100%";
}
function closeNav2() {
    document.getElementById("myNav2").style.height = "0%";
}    
function openNav3() {
    document.getElementById("myNav3").style.height = "100%";
}
function closeNav3() {
    document.getElementById("myNav3").style.height = "0%";
}
```

Add a `localStorage` statement:

```
function openNav1() {
    document.getElementById("myNav1").style.height = "100%";
    localStorage.setItem("myNav1", "true");
}
function closeNav1() {
    document.getElementById("myNav1").style.height = "0%";
    localStorage.setItem("myNav1", "false");
}
function openNav2() {
    document.getElementById("myNav2").style.height = "100%";
    localStorage.setItem("myNav2", "true");
}
function closeNav2() {
    document.getElementById("myNav2").style.height = "0%";
    localStorage.setItem("myNav2", "false");
}
function openNav3() {
    document.getElementById("myNav3").style.height = "100%";
    localStorage.setItem("myNav3", "true");
}
function closeNav3() {
    document.getElementById("myNav3").style.height = "0%";
    localStorage.setItem("myNav3", "false");
}
```

Then, at the top of your JavaScript code, add a `window.onload` which reads from `localStorage` which items are open, and which are shut, then performs the relevant actions:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var myNav1 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("myNav1"));
    var myNav2 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("myNav2"));
    var myNav3 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("myNav3"));
    if (myNav1) {
        openNav1();
    } else {
        closeNav1();
    }
    if (myNav2) {
        openNav2();
    } else {
        closeNav2();
    }
    if (myNav3) {
        openNav3();
    } else {
        closeNav3();
    }
}
```

The above looks a bit clunky and repetitive, but it works, and it doesn't use `eval`.

Comment: I racked my brain on this for hours last night. Today I see where it went wrong. The very last parenthesis in the window.onload function should not be there. It works now. Thank you!

Comment: Oh yes, my apologies @AliciaTaylor.